# Automatic width integer descriptor for input with Fortran

Tags: fortran

I wanted to use an automatic integer width descriptor in Fortran. I referred to [Output formatting: too much whitespace in gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844250/output-formatting-too-much-whitespace-in-gfortran?lq=1)

This question says that I can use `I0` and `F0.0` for "auto" width.
Here is my sample code (complied with GNU Fortran Compiler):

```
PROGRAM MAIN
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: i
REAL :: j

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter integer'
READ (*,100) i
100 FORMAT (I0)

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter real'
READ (*,110) j
110 FORMAT (F0.0)

WRITE (*,100) 'Integer = ',i
WRITE (*,110) 'Real = ',j

END PROGRAM
```

There is runtime error

```
(unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Positive width required in format
```

Am I mis-understanding the auto width descriptor? What option should I use?

Comment: just do list directed i/o on the reads (`read(*,*)`)

Comment: I was torn between suggesting http://stackoverflow.com/q/21170031 as a duplicate and answering.  In the end, I thought a clear statement of "no `I0` on input" to a focused question was sensible.

Comment: Note that the `I0` descriptor was added to the Fortran standard in the Fortran 95 revision - Fortran 90 (section 10.2.1) requires the width of the integer edit descriptor to be positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `I0` to specify a minimal field width is allowed for output.  For input, `I0` is not allowed.

From Fortran 2008, 10.7.2.1 (6) (my emphasis):

> On output, with I, B, O, Z, F, and G editing, the specified value of the field width w may be zero. In such cases, the processor selects the smallest positive actual field width that does not result in a field filled with asterisks. *The specified value of w shall not be zero on input.*

There is no clear alternative to `I0` for input, but as agentp comments, list-directed input (`read(*,*)`) is simple and may well be suitable for your needs.  If it isn't then you can look into more general parsing of lines read in as character variables.  You can [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170630) examples of this latter.

Comment: I got that `read(*,*)` should be used. But what when reading a matrix (say 5x5) from a file? First row will have 5 real numbers with varying width. Do you have any suggestion how to read such file?

Comment: If you want to read five real numbers with list-directed input just specify five reals in the input list: `read(*,*) a(1,1:5)`, say.  That's the same whether using an explicit format or list-directed.  The difference is that list-directed handles the varying width.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @francescalus 's and @agentp 's answers, be aware that format labels, e.g. `100 FORMAT (I0)` should be avoided.

Instead, simply include the `format` within the `read`, e.g. if you wanted to read an integer that is up to 8 characters wide, `READ(*,'(I8)') i`.

If you have a very lengthy format or a format that you re-use in several lines of code, save it in a character string:

```
character :: form*64
real      :: r1, r2

form = '(es13.6)'  ! e.g. 9.123456e+001

.
.
.

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter a number'
READ (*, form) r1
WRITE (*,*) 'Enter another number'
READ (*, form) r2
```