# Error in fortran, undefined reference to subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am writing a subroutine and main function to call it, but getting error as `undefined reference to ___`. I found one reason: When I save the main and subroutine in the same file, compile and run that file, everything runs perfectly. However, when I save them into different `.f90` files and try to run the main file, I get error. Is there any way I can make subroutine into a separate file and call into main calling program?

I got confused with another place - in the main program at `!------ERROR------` place. I referred to [Automatic width integer descriptor in fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572830/automatic-width-integer-descriptor-in-fortran-90) I can use `I0` as automatic width display indicator. But when I used the same, there is run time error `expected integer but got character.` Any idea about this?

```
! saved as sub_program.f90 file
SUBROUTINE sub_program (v1,v2,ctr)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: ctr
INTEGER, INTENT (OUT) :: v1,v2

SELECT CASE (ctr)
CASE (1)
v1=1
v2=0
CASE (2)
v1=0
v2=1
END SELECT

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE


! main calling program, saved as caller.f90
PROGRAM caller
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: v1,v2,ctr

    DO ctr = 1,2,1
        CALL sub_program (v1,v2,ctr)
        WRITE (*,100) 'STEP = ',ctr,'V1 = ',v1,'V2 = ',v2 !------ERROR------
        100 FORMAT (I0) 
    END DO

END PROGRAM
```

Thanks!

Comment: show the command used to compile

Comment: Please revisit the FORMAT statement, you try to write out 3 character strings and 3 integers with just one I0

Answer (score 2):

1. What is your compile command? For me, this compiles and runs normally

   ```
   gfortran caller.f90 foo.f90 && ./a.out
   ```
2. `I0` is an integer indicator, but some items following your `WRITE` statement are character strings. You can try, for example,

   ```
   100 FORMAT (3(A, I0, 1X))
   ```

   where `1X` refers to a space.

As a note, if formatting is not terribly important and you're only interested in seeing some quick results, you can use the free format output (`WRITE(*,*) ...`).

EDIT: I had incorrectly referred to `FORMAT` as obsolete.

Comment: "Obsolete" has a particular meaning in terms of the standard language - certain language features are denoted as obsolete as a warning that they may be removed completely in some later edition of the standard.  Format statements are not denoted as obsolete in this manner in Fortran 2008 or the current draft of the next standard revision.

Comment: I still use `FORMAT` occasionally. In this case I would do it like you suggest, but if I wanted to output a table with 8 strings, floats and integers intermixed, I would do it this way.

Comment: @IanH Pardon the misinformation. Indeed, my memory had failed me. Only something called assigned format has been removed.