# How to take specific number of integers at specific position form input line in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, format

i was trying to do something like this,

i will be given 5 numbers in 5 lines and my program should take only the ***i**th* integer from the ***i**th* line.

```
1  2 3 4 5
5 6   7 8 9
10 11   11   13 14
100     2000 300 2 1
7 77 777 7777      77777
```

so `1 6 11 2 77777` should be taken as input to a array sized 5

how to do it properly with loop?
(as you can see, the width of the integer and space between them may vary )

thank you.

**upd:**
i want to do this with a loop, so that i don't have to type it manually. Also i know it can be done with another array, but as i am learning `Format` so i am curious to know if it is possible to do this with formatting.

```
program selective
    implicit none
    integer a(5)
    integer ignore, i
    read(*,*) a(1), ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore
    read(*,*) ignore, a(2), ignore, ignore, ignore
    read(*,*) ignore, ignore, a(3), ignore, ignore
    read(*,*) ignore, ignore, ignore, a(4), ignore
    read(*,*) ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, a(5)
    write(*,*) (a(i), i=1,5)
end program selective
```

Comment: In the linked question you'll find the basics of how to "skip" columns in your input. Which column you want to read varies on each line, but it's a simple extension. If you have specific problems doing that, then (as in a previous comment) show your attempt for context.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , i am sorry, i was completely out of clue how to do it with formatting, so i couldn't provide any code. pardon me please.

Comment: @francescalus i've edited my question. so to be specific, i want to do it with formatting.

Comment: Reading such uneven columns with an explicit format (rather than list-directed input) is a tricky, but entirely different problem.  If you just want to read the diagonal then, in most cases, you really are better off using list-directed input.

Comment: @francescalus than you very much for your feedback! should i create another question for this purpose?

Comment: Another question would make sense, but first have a look at other questions on that topic (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21170031/3157076), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27846138/3157076) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29572830/3157076). Essentially, you need to parse the lines manually (rather than hope to find a format which will "work"). A new question should look at difficulties you have in parsing rather than asking about a format.

Comment: @francescalus i understand now, thank you very much for your kind co-operation :)